# ActiveRecord 'where' wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) when pulling in objects with a specific date window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to pull in an array of objects from a mongo database via AR based on both a 'publish' column and a 'start_on' date column:

```
@featured_events = Event.where(publish: "Featured").where("start_on >= ?", Date.today).order(:start_on).all
```

So I want objects where publish is set to the string "Featured" and the start_on date for the event is after today. But whenever I run any variation of this I get the error 'wrong number of arguments, (2 for 1)'. But everywhere I look confirms that

```
.where("start_on >= ?", Date.today)
```

is the correct way to do this, which requires two arguments. Could it have something to do with mongo?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Is `Event` an ActiveRecord model or a Mongoid model?

Comment: The model is stored in an external rails app that is backed by a mongo db. However, the models from that app are being pulled into the web app I'm working on. I have full activerecord access in the rails console on the working app to the models being stored in the external app, one of which is the Event model.

Comment: So what does `Event` look like? Does it subclass `ActiveRecord::Base`? Does it `include Mongoid::Document`?

Comment: Does not inherit from activerecord base:

class DateRangeError < StandardError; end
class Event
...

Comment: So where is it getting the `where` method from?

Comment: Good question. Perhaps a rake task from the app that is pulling the model in.

Comment: Do you have `class Event < ActiveRecord::Base` and `class Event; include Mongoid::Document` happening at the same time perhaps?

Comment: class Event < ActiveRecord::Base doesn't exist. Just the class Event in the tertiary app which holds all the models. So I obviously can use the 'where' clause to query on every column in the Event model, why wouldnt it allow me to do '.where("start_on >= ?", Date.today)' -- a pretty standard query? And thanks for your help.

Comment: So what does `Event.method(:where).inspect` have to say?

Comment: "#<Method: Class(Mongoid::Finders)#where>"

Comment: So your `Event` **is** a Mongoid model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.where("start_on >= ?", Date.today)` by `.where(:start_on.gte => Date.today)` and tell if it's what you are expecting.

Comment: Btw, you can try the `.lte` method :)